# Proof that $ n^{n} \leq {(n+1)}^{n} $

Tags: inequality, induction

I know this seems trivial, but how could I proof this? Should I use Induction?
Where $n$ is an integer.

Comment: $x^x=e^{x\ln x}$ is increasing on $[1,\infty[$

Comment: We have $n\le n+1$. So $n^k\le (n+1)^k$ for every positive integer $k$.

Comment: use binomial expansion.

Comment: Proving such claims is like shooting rockets on ants. For $n>0$, the equal-sign can be omitted. But if you do want a proof, you can do it with $n<n+1\ \rightarrow \ ln(n)<ln(n+1)\ \rightarrow \ n ln(n) < n ln(n+1)\ \rightarrow\ n^n<(n+1)^n$ for $n>0$.

Comment: You mean for every non-negative integer $n$.

Comment: $0^0$ is usually defined to be $1$, so $0^0=1^0=1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the binomial theorem,

$$
(n+1)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}n^i.
$$

One of the terms is $n^n$ and the rest are positive, so $(n+1)^n$ is $n^n+$something positive, and the inequality follows.

Comment: to prove a simple statement by use a rather complex one seems not a very useful idea to me.

Comment: @miracle173 Agreed, but this method doesn't require monotonicity of the power function to prove.

Answer (score 9):

$$
(n+1)^n = [n(1+1/n)]^n = n^n(1+1/n)^n \geq n^n\cdot1^n = n^n
$$

whenever $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is greater than or equal to $1$.

Comment: Dang. Beat me to it by mere seconds. Good job.

Comment: and why  $(1+1/n)^n \geq 1^n$? Because exponentiation is an increasing function? Then $(n+1)^n \geq n^n$ follows immediately.

Comment: @miracle173: That's an admissible point.  I would say that provided $n$ is a natural number, you can then show this secondary fact by induction: $1+1/n \geq 1$, and then $(1+1/n)^k = (1+1/n)(1+1/n)^{k-1} \geq (1+1/n)^{k-1}$.  But if $n$ is in general a real, then I would agree with you that the above is not a sufficient demonstration.

Comment: to prove $(1+1/n)^n \geq 1^n$ by induction is almost the same as to prove $n^{n} \leq {(n+1)}^{n}$. So this is not a proof at all. But it seems that some readers are excited by the formulas

Comment: @miracle173: Yeah, I guess.  I'm assuming that this appeals to the intuition of some people that the more direct approach does not.  (I.e., it's easier to see that $(1+1/n)^n > 1$ than the other).  I concede I'm occasionally perplexed by what gets votes here.

Comment: At first, I thought that it was asking about how to show $n^n \geq (n+1)^{n-1}$.  But no dice, apparently.

Answer (score 7):

From Andre's hint in the comments:

$$n \leq n + 1$$

In fact, strict inequality holds:

$$n < n + 1$$

Assuming $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (since I see that you've mentioned induction), we can raise both sides of the last inequality to the $n$th power:

$$n^n < (n + 1)^n.$$

This implies that

$$n^n \leq (n + 1)^n,$$

since $\leq$ is to be interpreted as *less than* **OR** *equal to*.

*QED*

Answer (score 5):

Induction is a good and simple way to prove 
$$a \lt b \implies a^n<b^n$$
for $ a,b,n \in \mathbb{N}$ because
$$a^{n+1}=a^n\cdot a<b^n \cdot b=b^{n+1}$$
From this your statement follows.